# Flutter Icons 3 dots

Tags: flutter, material-design

Does the material library of Flutter have the 3 dots icons

```
Icon(Icons.three_dots_overflow),
```

[image: er]

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Yes, the more_horiz:

```
    Icon(Icons.more_horiz);
```

[image]

and the more_vert:

```
    Icon(Icons.more_vert);
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Android**

[image]

**iOS**

[image]

---

To show the menu icon (based on the platform):

```dart
import 'dart:io';
// ...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('AppBar'),
      actions: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: Icon(Platform.isAndroid ? Icons.more_vert : Icons.more_horiz),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Icon(
   Icons.more_horiz_outlined,
   size: 25,
   color: Color(0xFF5F6368),
  ),
```

[image]

```
Icon(
    Icons.more_vert_outlined,
    size: 25,
    color: Color(0xFF5F6368),
   ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This icon is same

> Icon(Icons. pending_outlined);